# I think I abuse of Ressources.load

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok so I'm a bit confused about [Ressources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html). I actually use it quite a lot and everyone seems to see this feature as pure evilness. In this [documentation](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/temas/best-practices/resources-folder?playlist=30089), it's even written "Don't use it". I searched a lot about this and found [this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/319127/goods-and-bads-about-using-resourcesload.html). It mostly says to use Ressources.Load only for rare assets, otherwise, performance could/will be harmed.

I can see why this could be a "bad" thing to use, but honestly, I don't know how not to use this in my situation.

Lets say I have a game with ~10 different races with couples of units per race. The user chose it's race and start the game. At this point, it seems normal to me to Ressource.Load only the assets related to this specific race, and not the other ones...

Also, let's say you have a combat scene, with many possible environments (ie: winter, forest, desert, etc.). Again, I wouldn't want to load anything else than the one I'm fighting on. So using Ressources.Load seems the perfect tool. No? Am I missing something important about Unity or what?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that Unity loads everything it see that is connected to things in the inspector in the scene. You have no way to stop Unity's loading once you are in the scene. (You can unload later, but it already took the toll of loading them all) **The performance harmed** in Unity's term seems to mean while playing, because if you connect them to the scene it loads everything from start and plays smooth from then but if you do a dynamic load you risk in lagging while playing.

> Don't use it.
>
> This strong recommendation is made for several reasons:
>
> Use of the Resources folder makes fine-grained memory management more
>   difficult.

It's difficult but not impossible. If you are careful on your own, then you can reap the reward that is lower memory consumption.

> Improper use of Resources folders will increase application
>   startup time and the length of builds. As the number of Resources
>   folders increases, management of the Assets within those folders
>   becomes very difficult.

It can't be help because offsetting with the load time you can save at scene start, the increased startup time is probably worth it. Most player won't mind the startup time in my opinion.

> The Resources system degrades a project's
>   ability to deliver custom content to specific platforms and eliminates
>   the possibility of incremental content upgrades. AssetBundle Variants
>   are Unity's primary tool for adjusting content on a per-device basis.

Then you only put things that works universally in the Resources folder.

A modern alternate way is to compose your game in scene and use `LoadSceneMode.Additive` to get what you want one by one. It is suitable for big chunks like combat scene, but for lazy loading of something small in concept (but potentially contains large data like textures) like characters I would still use `Resources.Load`. The only thing that has delayed load build in is `AudioClip` which you can deselect preload audio data.

I wrote a detailed load process and its memory consumption here if you are interested in reading. 
https://gametorrahod.com/unity-texture-memory-loading-unloading-7054819e4ae8